# array_sum return raw numbers without sum - php

Tags: php

I am using Array_sum like this

```
    <?php
     $totalAmount = $db->prepare('SELECT
     a.proId, a.userId,
     b.id, b.pPrice
     FROM purchaseshistory AS a
     INNER JOIN products AS b ON(a.proId=b.id)
     WHERE a.userId=?');
     $totalAmount->bind_param('i', $cus['cId']);
     $totalAmount->execute();
          $totalAmount->bind_result($proId, $userId, $id, $pPrice);
$totalAmount->store_result();
   while ($totalAmount->fetch()) {
     $sum = 0;
     $amount = $pPrice;
     $amount = is_array($amount) ? $amount : array($amount);
          foreach ($amount as $item => $value) {
           $sum += $value;
}
print $sum;
}
?>
```

and also tried to make it like this

```
while ($totalAmount->fetch()) {
       $amount = array($pPrice);
       print array_sum($amount) ;
}
```

same results I get the numbers like 200150200

Comment: because in your second code block, `$amount` is not an  array is it, so it's just printing the value each time, you need to push the item price to `$amount` as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amount = [];
while ($totalAmount->fetch()) {
       $amount[] = $pPrice;
}
echo array_sum($amount);
```

You're not adding elements to an array.. the code above is and should work as you expect

Update for older PHP versions

```
$amount = array();
while ($totalAmount->fetch()) {
       $amount[] = $pPrice;
}
echo array_sum($amount);
```

Comment: it works fine locally but online I got error 

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in **** on line 71` line 71 content `$amount = [];` any Idea thanks for helping

Comment: Ah OK it looks like a PHP version issue, Ill update my answer

Comment: Thanks I got it I changed it to `$amount = array();` now it working fine online too thanks again

Comment: @YousefAltaf no problem

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (without using array_sum()):-

```
$sum = 0;
while ($totalAmount->fetch()) {
  $sum += $pPrice;
}
echo $sum;
```